# <br> not breaking onto new line, view source also displaying <br>

Tags: html, css, jsp

```
<td class="accessorybgcolor13" colspan="3"> Hood switch - (automatic transmission only).&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;Hood Switch (2013 CX-5 - not required for cars with factory alarm. Required for all 2014 Models. Not required for 2014 Mazda3 with 2TE package. Standard on 2016 Mazda6 GT)</td>
```

In the browser this is displaying like `&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;` and not breaking the line.

In view source it is displaying `&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;`, 
why is the line not breaking but instead displaying the text `&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;`?

Comment: Why don't you just use a normal br?

Comment: In view source also displaying <br><br>

Comment: sorry guys i am writing the &lt;&gt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using [HTML Entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) instead of HTML tags. if you want to insert a line break you must use HTML tags as following.

```
<td class="accessorybgcolor13" colspan="3"> Hood switch - (automatic transmission only).<br><br>Hood Switch (2013 CX-5 - not required for cars with factory alarm. Required for all 2014 Models. Not required for 2014 Mazda3 with 2TE package. Standard on 2016 Mazda6 GT)</td>
```

**Note:** you are viewing the source in DevTools not the page source, that is why it shows 
 instead of entities

Comment: i am using same like this but displaying  page has Hood switch - (automatic transmission only).<br><br>Hood Switch (2013 CX-5 - not required for cars with factory alarm. Required for all 2014 Models. Not required for 2014 Mazda3 with 2TE package. Standard on 2016 Mazda6 GT)

Comment: line is not breaking displaying <br><br>

Comment: replace .&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt; with <br><br> now ti will work. because .&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt; are HTML entities and it will not be treated as HTML tag but it will print the desired character on the browser window.

Comment: It displaying <br><br>

Comment: can you show me your output? and which browser are you using?

Comment: sorry guys i am writing the &lt;&gt

Comment: @mahesh &lt; &gt; are the HTML entities , &lt;  =  <  and  &gt;  =  > , this is what I was saying and if my answer helped you, you should accept it by clicking the tick mark at the top left of my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your string is html encoded. That's why you see 
 in the web page. Just use a normal `<br>` tag like below.

```
<td class="accessorybgcolor13" colspan="3"> Hood switch - (automatic transmission only).<br>Hood Switch (2013 CX-5 - not required for cars with factory alarm. Required for all 2014 Models. Not required for 2014 Mazda3 with 2TE package. Standard on 2016 Mazda6 GT)</td>
```

Comment: In View source also displaying <br><br>

Comment: What do you mean by view source? How does this display in the web browser?

Comment: when rightclick on browser click on viewsource link

Comment: Of course it does. View source page shows the actual html tags of the page. Why is it a problem?

Comment: In View source displaying <br><br> html view also displaying <br><br>

Comment: Try adding a div outside the string like,
<td>
<div>Hood switch - (automatic transmission only).<br>Hood Switch (2013 CX-5 - not required for cars with factory alarm. Required for all 2014 Models. Not required for 2014 Mazda3 with 2TE package. Standard on 2016 Mazda6 GT)</div></td>

Comment: @mahesh you are viewing the source in DevTools but not the page source

Comment: sorry guys i am writing the &lt;&gt;